# How to select all columns in dplyr/sql?

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr

I am connecting a MySQL data base with `dplyr` and handle the data with `dplyr` and the `%>%` operatot subsequently.

```
conDplyr <- src_mysql(user = db_user, password = db_pw, dbname = db_name, host = db_host, port = some_port)
```

As long as I select a certain number of columns but all, it works!

```
dat <- conDplyr %>%
 tbl('table_name') %>%
 select(c1, c2, c3, c4) %>%
 filter(!is.null(c4))
```

Now, I ran over a use case, in which I need to select all columns (whole table). All tutorials I found (about `dplyr`) handled this by selecting the whole dataframe (which I do not have)

```
some_dataframe <- ...
select(some_dataframe)
```

I have not found any suggestions in combination with databases. Perhaps the day was too long. Does anybody could help me please?

Best Rob

```
conDplyr <- src_mysql(...)
dat <- conDplyr %>%
tbl('table_name') %>%
select(everything()) %>%
filter(!is.null(ean))
```

works just fine. Thanks! If I leave out the select the query results in an error (non-defined columns selected).
Again, I did not just want to work with a already existing data frame, but with a table queried from a database, that`s why I am have to do, correct me if I am wrong, an select.

Comment: In select you have to pass variable names. It's not going to work if you say select("your dataframe"). Can you simply ignore the select command and proceed with what you want to do like in any other dplyr process? If you don't use select it will automatically use all columns.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As @AntoniosK pointed out I do not know why you would like to do that. However, have you tried `everything`?:

```
some_dataframe <- ...
select(everything())
```

For instance:

```
select(iris, everything()) # or
iris %>% select(everything())
```

Comment: Didn't know about `everything()`. But it is quite useful in a function where the user can specify which columns to keep, and if the user have not specified any columns, then give all columns. I have used your reply like this: `dplyr::select(dplyr::all_of(columns) %||% tidyselect::everything())`