# Trying to use dplyr to select/filter data in a SQL database in R

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, dbi

For one of my assignments I have to use dplyr to select/filter information from a SQL database that's been loaded into R. I have successfully connected to the database but I am having trouble using dplyr to sort through the tables.

Here is my code:

```
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)
library(dplyr)
conn <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), "richardtwatson.com", 
dbname="ClassicModels", user="student", password="student")
t <- select(conn, customerNumber.Customers)
```

I keep getting this error message:

> Error in UseMethod("select_") :
>   no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('MySQLConnection', 'DBIConnection', 'DBIObject')".

If someone could steer me in the right direction that would be great, I am new to R programming. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you need something like `src_sql`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209396/how-to-select-all-columns-in-dplyr-sql

Comment: You have to call `tbl` first before you can use `dplyr`: `tbl(conn, "Payments")`.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use dplyr syntax via ODBC/DBI, instead of SQL:

1. Connect to your preferred database with dbConnect (as above)
2. Point to table  `t <- tbl(conn, 'some_table')`
3. Query table with  `t %>% select(some_col_1, some_col_2) %>% filter(some_col == 'some_crit')`
4. Don't forget to disconnect  `dbDisconnect(conn)`

This method translate dplyr to SQL, before running in server. I find for some operations, you need to first convert to tibble  `%>% as_tibble()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the functions from the DBI package to send or get the query and write down the SQL query in the function with SELECT.
Examples here : https://db.rstudio.com/dbi/

```
conn <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
"richardtwatson.com",dbname="ClassicModels", user="student", password="student")

t <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM customerNumber.Customers")
```